# Authentication protocol over Bluetooth

Tags: security, authentication, bluetooth

I'm doing some research about authentication protocols, specifically over Bluetooth. My system will not have an Internet connection but I want to authenticate, authorize and encrypt my communications. Are there any known protocols that I should look into? A few requirements:

- A one time authentication for the master user
- Ability to grant limited access to other users (e.g. generating a time based token)

Thank you for possible answers and suggestions.